# How can I use Static Broadcast Receiver or similar service in Android API 30 device?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

I want to schedule a task for every minute on my application and want the task to be executed even when the application/activity is not opened in foreground. How can I achieve that? I am running my application on an Android emulator on API 30.

Answer (score 0):

Please use JobScheduler to schedule a job. From the documentation of Android Job Scheduler is an
"API for scheduling various types of jobs against the framework that will be executed in your application's own process."

Detailed documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler?hl=en

Comment: I tried using JobScheduler, however using that it does not allow me to schedule task at a frequency of less 15 minutes. I want a frequency of 1 minute.